# Error message while trying to add foreign key annotation in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm following a a course on Udemy building a .net and mvc5 project. This project involves using the code first design philosophy for databases.

Initially the exception I have is

> Invalid column name 'Genre_Id1'

I've searched for Genre_Id1 in the entire solution, checked my classes but I'm not quite sure where it is defining or picking up this column name.

So then I tried to specify manually

```
[ForeignKey("Genre_Id")]
```

but when I tried to add migration after this change , it is unsuccessful and shows message as below

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
> Movie_Genre_Target_Movie_Genre_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. **The type of property 'Genre_Id' on entity 'Movie' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'Genre' in the referential constraint 'Movie_Genre'**

As I am a newbie - any help would be much more appreciated. Thanks
Movie.cs

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
       
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public int NumberInStock { get; set; }

       
        public byte Genre_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Genre_Id")]
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    }
```

Genre.cs

```
public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code classes ! What do `Movie` and `Genre` look like?

Comment: @marc_s I have added Movie.cs and Genre.cs to above post. Thank you for looking into.

Comment: It can't be `byte` (*must be the same as the corresponding property types*).

Comment: One problem is: `Genre.Id` is an `int`, while the `Movie.Genre_Id` is a `byte` - those datatypes **must be identical** if you want to establish a foreign key relationship! That's what the error you're getting is telling you - fix it by making `Movie.Genre_Id` an `int` and then your FK constraint should work just fine

Comment: @JassSanghera: The error message describes the problem: **_The type of property 'Genre_Id' on entity 'Movie' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'Genre' in the referential constraint 'Movie_Genre'_**

Comment: changing "byte" to "int" allowed me to successfully add-migration. However, when I update-database it gives me "Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed objtype (COLUMN) is wrong." What it means.

Comment: That's an entirely different question that can't be handled in comments.